# How to add PyQt plugin into py2app

Tags: pyqt, py2app

I was trying to add the plugin "plugins/bearer/qgenericbearer4" to a PyQt app.

Though i had added

```
`'qt_plugins'     : ['bearer',],`
```

to the OPTIONS in the setup.py my application still can't use the plugin.

If i'm doing anything wrong please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a sample project that demonstrates the problem?

This may be fixed in py2app 0.8 (current release), I've merged a bug fix that affected support for Qt plugins.

Comment: Hi Ronald, Thanks for replying. Here's a stripped down minimal version of the code. Here plugins were needed for the captcha to be displayed. When bundled into an app Py2App didn't copy the plugins under images.

Comment: Sorry missed the link https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3xtp372hjxg7l1t/QPL4ixTauA. Note: Run webViewUtil.py. In a similar fashion, bearer plugins were required for few other websites to work. If you need more information please do ask me. Expecting a fix sooner ;).